Character limit in a regular expression Javascript
Regular expression requirements:

from 3 to 5 characters,

at least one capital letter,

and at least one number.


My expression now looks like this.
The character limit does not work.
/((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)){3,5}/


how are you testing/using this RE?

These shouldn't all be in a single regular expression. Even if it could be done, it would be horribly opaque, confusing, and unmaintainable. Have one to check for a capital letter, one to check for a number, and check the length. Then AND these conditions together.

{3,5} has to be after a pattern that matches something. You put it after lookaheads, which don't match anything by themselves. Put a . before it to match a character. And you also need to anchor the regexp so it will match the entire input, not just part of it.
/((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d))^.{3,5}$/

